# Set of values of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If the inequality
>   $$(1-a^2)x^2+(2a-3)x+1<0$$
>   is true for all values of $a$ then the set of values of $x$ is?

I took two cases (the parabola opens upwards and the parabola opens downwards). For the first case the value of $x$ is all real except the interval containing roots. For the second case the value of $x$ is the interval containing the roots. I couldn't proceed with this as I couldn't eliminate $a$. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If the quadratic expression is always negative, then its graph must lie below the $x$-axis, so it has no real roots.

Comment: Why don't you solve the associated quadratic equation in $x$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to consider the LHS as a polynomial in $a$, rather than $x$.
$$x^2-a^2x^2+2ax-3x+1<0$$
$$(-x^2)a^2+(2x)a+x^2-3x+1<0$$
Because of the $-x^2$ coefficient of $a^2$, the parabola opens downwards. For the inequality to hold for all $a$, the discriminant must be negative:
$$(2x)^2-4(-x^2)(x^2-3x+1)<0$$
$$4x^4-12x^3+8x^2<0$$
$$4x^2(x^2-3x+2)<0$$
Since $x=0$ does not satisfy the inequality, we may divide by $4x^2$:
$$x^2-3x+2<0$$
$$(x-1)(x-2)<0$$
$$1<x<2$$

Comment: Nice approach! Didn't think of this ever

Comment: Hello: sorry for the off-topic comment, but I lack other ways to contact you. In [this review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/921820) you "improved" in which the user, in an attempt to ask me a question, edited erroneous content into my solution. Another user rejected the suggested edit, but unfortunately the Community User went ahead and broke the tie in your favor. The user's edit comment made it clear that they were asking a question, so next time while reviewing, be sure to glance at the user's comment to see if it alerts you that the edit should be rejected. Thanks.

Comment: I've already rolled back everything to an OK state, so things have been straightened out already.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(1-a^2\right)x^2+(2 a-3) x+1<0$$

Expand and collect wrt $a$

$$-a^2 x^2+2 a x+\left(x^2-3 x+1\right)<0$$

Multiply both sides by $-1$ and change the $<$ into $>$

$$a^2x^2-2ax-\left(x^2-3 x+1\right)>0$$

This is true for any $a$ if and only if the discriminant $\Delta$ of the polynomial

$P(a)=a^2x^2-2ax-\left(x^2-3 x+1\right)$ is negative

$\Delta=4x^2+4x^2(x^2-3x+1)=4x^2(x-2) (x-1)<0$

That is $\color{red}{1<x<2}$

Hope this is useful